# App crash because of SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am 100 percent sure that everything is connected properly yet I keep getting a SIGABRT error.

Here is the code for SelectViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SelectViewController: UIViewController {

var accounttype = 0

@IBAction func AdminButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func ParentButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func DriverButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func StudentButton(_ sender: Any) {
    accounttype = 1
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    var SubmitController = segue.destination as! SubmitViewController
    SubmitController.john = accounttype;

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Here is the code for SubmitViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SelectViewController: UIViewController {

var accountType = 0

@IBAction func AdminButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func ParentButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func DriverButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func StudentButton(_ sender: Any) {
    accountType = 1
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? SubmitViewController {
        destination.john = accountType
        print("Inside if statement")
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     print("Out of if statement")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Here is the console:

```
2018-08-28 17:17:56.529276-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005170] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.50001000 started
2018-08-28 17:17:56.529921-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005170] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2018-08-28 17:17:57.024884-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005198] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-08-28 17:17:57.025067-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005198] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-08-28 17:18:01.737912-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005175] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-08-28 17:18:01.738363-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005175] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-08-28 17:18:03.755460-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005196] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2018-08-28 17:18:03.755664-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1005196] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
Could not cast value of type 'SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController' (0x10d8349d0) to 'SchoolDrive.SubmitViewController' (0x10d834820).
2018-08-28 17:18:04.613651-0700 SchoolDrive[5178:1004484] Could not cast value of type 'SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController' (0x10d8349d0) to 'SchoolDrive.SubmitViewController' (0x10d834820).
(lldb)
```

I am very grateful for all help and all help is appreciated. Thank you in advance. I need all help as fast as I can get it. This will make it easier for me. Again thank you so much for all the hep and I am very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crashing in you case because of the force cast to fix that use `if let` or `guard` to prevent crashing. Modify your code in `prepare(for:, sender:)` method to below.

```
if let destination = segue.destination as? SubmitViewController {
  destination.john = accountType
}
```

or

```
guard let destination = segue.destination as? SubmitViewController else {
  return 
}

destination.john = accountType
```

Comment: I put your top code in my code and the app ran smoothly. But in SubmitViewController I have an "if condition" that is not running despite all requirements being met and I would like to know why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question with `SubmitViewController` code. So that I can have a look at it.

Comment: I will do that. I also realized via printing that the variable john is still 0 and that is why the if statement is not being fufilled

Comment: @Polifrog you can accept the answer if the answer helped you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test segue.destination to make sure it is a SubmitViewController before just casting it with as!. The stack trace says the type of that instance if SecondRegisterViewController.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error says, you might bind destination segue to wrong VC(SecondRegisterViewController). And expected is SubmitViewController.
For a safer way, use method like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueApplicationToSubmitControllerVC"
        {
            if let SubmitControllerVC = segue.destination as? SubmitViewController
            {
                SubmitControllerVC.john = accounttype

            }
        }
    }
```